# ADB On A BATCH Script

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I Get Errors Like "cannot stat: blah blah" How Can I Fix It??

Heres The Code:

```
adb start-server
adb wait-for-device
adb shell mkdir /sdcard/XMD
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\xbin\xmd /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\XMD /sdcard/XMD/ 
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\busybox /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\init.d\08Optimizer /sdcard/XMD/
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\xbin\xmd /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\XMD /sdcard/XMD/ 
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\busybox /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD/XMD\v1.10\etc\init.d\08Optimizer /sdcard/XMD/
```

to

```
adb -d push C:\XMD\XMD\v1.10\xbin\xmd /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD\XMD\v1.10\etc\XMD /sdcard/XMD/ 
adb -d push C:\XMD\XMD\v1.10\etc\busybox /sdcard/XMD/
adb -d push C:\XMD\XMD\v1.10\etc\init.d\08Optimizer /sdcard/XMD/
```